# What wrong with php my loop

Tags: php, loops, while-loop

I have a small PHP script

```
<?php

    $index = 1;

    while($index <= 5) {

        $qry="SELECT * FROM service_cost WHERE id_serv_cost=".$index;

        echo "<br/>".$qry."<br/>";
        $results=mysql_query($qry);

        echo "<br/>".print_r($results)."<br/>";
        $ligne=mysql_fetch_assoc($results);

        echo "<br/>".print_r($ligne)."<br/>";

        $coul='white';

        if ( $t_price[1]==$index)
            $coul='F4C6C6';

        echo "<tr>".
        "<td style='padding-right:10px;font-weight:bold;align=right>".$index."</td>".
        "<td>".$ligne['min_call']."</td>".
        "<td>$".sprintf("%4.2f",$ligne['positive_answer_price'])."</td>".
        "<td>$".sprintf("%4.2f",$ligne['random_caller_id_price'])."</td>".
        "<td>$".sprintf("%4.2f",$ligne['voice_message_price'])."</td>".
        "<td>$".sprintf("%4.2f",$ligne['call_back_price'])."</td>".
        "<td>$".sprintf("%4.2f",$ligne['unanswered_price'])."</td>".
        "<td>$".sprintf("%4.2f",$ligne['transaction_fee'])."</td>".
        "<td>$".sprintf("%4.2f",$ligne['transaction_cost'])."</td>".
        "</tr>";

        $index = $index + 1;
    }

?>
```

I see my "echo $qry" only 3 times and in my table there is only 2 rows

the $index in the "echo $qry" are (1,3,5) but in the table, the displayed $index are (2,4)

In my DB there is 5 rows

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you are getting data from the same database / table ? In the other hand, this is indeed not a clean way of coding.

Comment: Yes I am getting the data from the right db / table (tested in phpmyadmin) In the picture you can see 3 times SELECT * FROM service_cost WHERE id_serv_cost=X We should see it five times ?

Comment: is this your actual code, or a cut/copy/paste/edit? My guess is that you have an extra `$index = $index + 1;` somewhere between `$ligne=mysql_fetch_assoc($results);` and when you display your table row.

Comment: Can you show the output of 

`$qry="SELECT * FROM service_cost";`
`$result=mysql_query($qry);`
`while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) print_r($row);`

Comment: @seb, in reply to your comment yes, if there are five rows in the database, and you are not incrementing $index twice in the original code it should return five rows.